# W: GPG error: http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu scrapy InRelease:

Tags: apt-get, ubuntu-18.04

When I use apt-get update, I get this error: W: GPG error: http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu scrapy InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: 65D1B1CE9BCE5D04D51464F58F62CB1F627220E7
E: The repository 'http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu scrapy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I have tried many times to change the sources, but it still get the same error. 
And use the 'keyserver' to solve this question, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue this command upgrades which are held back by sudo apt-get upgrade

use sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Answer (score 0):

The wrong reason is the third party source. 'sudo gedit /etc/apt/source.list.d/scrapy.list'.
Found that there is an exception in the update sources. Use ping to test URLs, like this 'sudo ping c2 urls'.